# npx create-react-app cannot be instantiated in the command line interface

Tags: reactjs

how can i do my network settings to make create-my-app to succesfully get installed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSUvd.png)
i have tried to run the command npx create-react-app my-app but the error keeps showing up. unfortunately i am incapable of doing my network configurations. please anybody who can help me configure this error that keeps on poping up on the command line interface. The error below is the copy paste from the cmd after trying to install create-react-app my-app.
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Wisekid254\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-20T08_38_42_912Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Wisekid254\Desktop>'npm help config'
''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Wisekid254\Desktop>npm help config

C:\Users\Wisekid254\Desktop>

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message you are encountering indicates a network related issue, possibly due to a connectivity problem, a proxy issue, or a temporary problem with the npm registry. Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

1. Check Your Internet Connection:
   Ensure that your internet connection is stable and working properly.
2. Retry the Command.
3. Use a mirror for npm registry:
   "npm config set registry [https://registry.npmjs.org/"](https://registry.npmjs.org/%22)
4. Clear npm Cache.
5. Try creating react-app using yarn.
6. Use a node version manager(NVM):
   If none of the above solutions work, consider using a Node.js version
   manager like NVM. This allows you to easily switch between different
   Node.js versions, and it might help with compatibility issues.

Install NVM by following the instructions here: https://github.com/nvm-
sh/nvm

After installing NVM, use it to install and switch to a different Node.js
version, and then try running the create-react-app command again.

Comment: Thanks so much Nishat, after ensuring i have  got strong internet connection the problem is solved.